# How do I get my remaining quota of translations from microsoft translator programmatically?

Tags: api, azure, translation, microsoft-translator, azure-marketplace

I want to keep track of how many translations I have left and use this to enable/disable functionality.

Is there a public API I can use to get this information?

Comment: Why the -1? I don't see anything wrong with the above question. I need this information also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No API that I know of, but the subscription page updates in near-realtime - see [this blog post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsofttranslator/thread/f688573c-9832-4c7a-9470-5c98f6f7ad42) from a few weeks ago for an update to this, including low-balance notifications on the subscription page.

For reference, here's the [API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576287).